# How to prevent QPlainText area from scrolling to end of line?

Tags: qt, pyside

When appending text longer than the widget's width with word wrap set to `NoWrap`, how do I prevent the view from moving to the end of the line like in the second image?

What I want:

[image]

What I get:

[image]

Code for re-creating the above image(s):

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw


class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._plain_text_edit = qtw.QPlainTextEdit()
        self._plain_text_edit.appendPlainText(' '.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 101)))
        self.setCentralWidget(self._plain_text_edit)
        self._plain_text_edit.setLineWrapMode(qtw.QPlainTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.show()

app = qtw.QApplication()
mw = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

This one example has a single line but the actual program will have multiple lines increasing throughout the run of the program. I'm using a `QPlainText` edit to display logs. I've tried moving the cursor, but I want the user to be able to select the text even when there's text being added and moving the cursor resets the selection every new line added.

Edit:
An MRE for a situation more similar to my actual program:

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PySide6 import QtCore


class MainWindow(qtw.QTabWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._plain_text_edit = qtw.QPlainTextEdit()
        self._plain_text_edit.setLineWrapMode(qtw.QPlainTextEdit.NoWrap)

        self._button = qtw.QPushButton("Press to add text.")
        self._button.clicked.connect(
            lambda:
                self._plain_text_edit.appendPlainText(
                    ' '.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 101))
                )
        )

        self.addTab(self._button, "Nothing")
        self.addTab(self._plain_text_edit, "edit")
        self.show()

app = qtw.QApplication()
mw = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Try `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)`

Comment: @Alexey doesn't work, the scroll bar is gone but the behavior still exists.

Comment: @オパラ This is just an artefact of your example. If the text is added after the window is shown, the view won't be scrolled (e.g. `QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self._plain_text_edit.appendPlainText(' '.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 101))))`).

Comment: @ekhumoro , Is there no other way to do it? I don't actually have a `show()` specific for the `PlainTextEdit`, it's a sub-widget hidden in a separate tab so I'm guessing the drawing happens when the user changes to that tab. I don't know how I would apply what you've suggested with that.

Comment: @オパラ As I said: the behaviour is just an artefact of *the particular example code shown in your question*. If you want a proper solution, you will need to show a more realistic example that better represents your actual application (i.e. a [mre]).

Comment: @ekhumoro I have updated the post with an MRE, please have a look.

Comment: @オパラ I don't really see the issue. On the first append, the caret moves to the end of the line (no real surprise there - it has to go *somewhere*). However, if the user subsequently moves the caret or makes a selection, the current scroll position is automatically maintained. So all you need to do is initialise the caret position to wherever you want it after the first append.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple. Before adding the text, get the selection (anchor and cursor position) and after adding the text, just restore the selection.

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui

def appendPlainTextAndKeepCursor(text_edit, text):
    tc = text_edit.textCursor()
    if tc.atEnd():
        # store the current selection
        anchor = tc.anchor()
        position = tc.position()

        # change the text
        text_edit.appendPlainText(text)

        # restore the selection
        tc.setPosition(anchor)
        tc.setPosition(position, QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
        text_edit.setTextCursor(tc)
    else:
        # just add the text
        text_edit.appendPlainText(text)


class MainWindow(qtw.QTabWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._plain_text_edit = qtw.QPlainTextEdit()
        self._plain_text_edit.setLineWrapMode(qtw.QPlainTextEdit.NoWrap)

        self._button = qtw.QPushButton("Press to add text.")
        self._button.clicked.connect(lambda: appendPlainTextAndKeepCursor(self._plain_text_edit, ' '.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 101))))

        self.addTab(self._button, "Nothing")
        self.addTab(self._plain_text_edit, "edit")
        self.show()

app = qtw.QApplication()
mw = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

Comment: This is totally redundant - the default implementation does this anyway (and also maintains the scroll position).

Comment: @ekhumoro No, it does not. If the current cursor is at the end of the text, then appending new text moves the cursor. And moving the cursor is the exact issue which OP experienced.

Comment: Yes, it does. Just move the caret (or make a selection) after the first append. There's no need to do anything else.

Comment: @ekhumoro The OP described a problem that if he appends a text, then the cursor (under certain circumstances) is by default moved to the end of the appended text. And he does not want that. So I suggested a solution which always restores the cursor to its original position before appending the text. As OP accepted this answer, it seems that this really solves his problem at hand. So I do not understand your objections.

Comment: See my first comment. The default implementation does a better job, because it also maintains the scroll position. Your function is unnecessarily inefficient, because it resets the caret after every append, when that only needs to be done *once* (i.e. only following the first append when the editor starts empty).

Comment: You are wrong. 1) My solution does maintain the scroll position too. 2) The problem which OP observed occurs not only when editor starts with empty text but whenever the cursor is at the end of document before adding the text. This includes when selection ends at the end of the document. 3) Yes, my solution is general and does not try to handle each specific case. It is also perfectly readable. 4) Being maybe "suboptimal"? I do not care, because it just works. Of course you can develop a more "optimal" solution by adding a few `if`s. It is trivial. You can post it as an alternative answer.

Comment: OK, I added one line `if tc.atEnd():` and `else:` which will make it more "optimal" but more verbose. I hope @ekhumoro will be happy now.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason scrolling occurs only if you `appendPlainText` before widget become visible, so 0-second timer solves your problem.

```py
from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc
qtc.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self._plain_text_edit.appendPlainText(' '.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 101))))
```

Alternatively you can force first draw and spin event loop before adding text to achieve same effect.

```py
self.show()
qtw.QApplication.processEvents()
self._plain_text_edit.appendPlainText(' '.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 101)))
```

In case of complex layout you can use eventFilter to unscroll horizontal scrollbar after show event:

```py
from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc

class EventFilter(qtc.QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, e):
        if e.type() == qtc.QEvent.Show:
            if isinstance(obj, qtw.QPlainTextEdit):
                qtc.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: obj.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(0))
                return False
        return super().eventFilter(obj, e)

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        filter = EventFilter()
        self._plain_text_edit.installEventFilter(filter)
        self._filter = filter
```

Comment: Is there no other way to do it? I don't actually have a `show()` specific for the `PlainTextEdit`, it's a sub-widget hidden in a separate tab so I'm guessing the drawing happens when the user changes to that tab. I don't know how I would apply what you've suggested with that.